# "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file". Electron+Vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron, babeljs

I am trying to use the npm package "Typeorm" in my Electron + Vue project, but when I run it I have this error:

```
    Module parse failed: Unexpected character '​' (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import { EntitySchema } from "typeorm"
> ​
| export default new EntitySchema({
|     name: "Post", // Will use table name `post` as default behaviour.
```

But I don't even have a webpack.config.js in my project. Not even inside files from frameworks that i'm using. So I can't follow the tips of this https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders.

The file that contains this import:
**Category.js**

```
import { EntitySchema } from "typeorm"

export default new EntitySchema({
    name: "Category", // Will use table name `category` as default behaviour.
    tableName: "categories", // Optional: Provide `tableName` property to override the default behaviour for table name.
    columns: {
        id: {
            primary: true,
            type: "int",
            generated: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: "varchar",
        },
    },
})
```

This is my **Babel.config:**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

To try to make it work, in my vue.config.js I added this "transpileDependecies", as suggested in [@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/babel.html) . But it stills the same error.

**vue.config.js**

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: [
   'typeorm'
  ],
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
  },

  pluginOptions: {
    vuetify: {
            // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vuetify-loader
        }
  }
})
```

Other similar questions did not help..

Comment: @loganfsmyth could you please help?